# Rust subtyping/"runtime polymorphism"/using traits in Boxes

Tags: rust, polymorphism, subtyping

Consider the following dumbed-down example:

```
pub trait ThemePark<A, V>
where
    A: Attraction,
    V: Visitor,
{
    fn create(square_size: u32, name: &str) -> Self;
    fn get_attractions(&self) -> Vec<A>;
    fn get_visitors(&self) -> Vec<V>;
}

pub trait Attraction {}
pub trait Visitor {}
```

A concrete `ThemePark` could have an arbitrary set of attractions, as well as visitors. They are implemented with structs:

```
struct ElderlyWhiteMale;
impl Visitor for ElderlyWhiteMale {}
```

A `ThemePark` is wrapped in some company's assets, like so:

```
pub struct Asset<'a> {
    name: &str,
    theme_park: Box<ThemePark<> + 'a> // <-- This won't compile, as ThemePark needs 2 type arguments
}
```

This begins my pain. I put `ThemePark` in a `Box` because I don't know the size of it at compile time. It could be wrapped around any kind of `Attraction` and `Visitor`.

`ThemePark` needs 2 type arguments, but I can't know them at compile-time. Somewhere in my code I read this from an external file and build a `ThemePark` accordingly.

The idea is, that at runtime I can create a `ThemePark` from an external source and then invoke the `functions` defined in the trait on it.

```
impl Asset {
    fn init_and_query() -> () {
        let theme_park: Box<ThemePark> = match external_file.get_theme_park_type {
            ThemeParkType::FUN => unimplemented! {"There is no fun, yet!"},
            ThemeParkType::SERIOUS => {
                println!("Creating serious themepark");

                SeriousThemePark::create(size /*...*/)
            }
        };

        let attractions = theme_park.get_attractions();
        // ... Do something with the attractions
    }
}

pub enum ThemeParkType {
    FUN,
    SERIOUS,
}
```

I understand that I can't put the `ThemePark` as-is on the stack... it's size is unknown at compile time, so the compiler can't know what to allocate.

That's why I either use a reference `&` or wrap it in a `Box` like I do here.

I understand there is type erasure, meaning that I would get back only a `ThemePark` and not a `SeriousThemePark`, but that would suffice for the moment.

Am I using traits all wrong here? How would you go and fix that. Coming from Java/Scala/C++ I seem to be stuck too deep in existing thinking.

Comment: Could you show how you are going to implement some `ThemePark`s, let's say, `impl ThemePark<???, ???> for FunIsland { ??? }`?

Comment: You should go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), specifically the chapter about [*trait objects*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust polymorphism is very similar to C++ polymorphism in that regard; it features:

- compile-time polymorphism, to parameterize an item with types known at compile-time,
- run-time polymorphism, when the concrete types are not known at compile-time.

Rust uses `trait` to define an *interface* which is then used to both constrain compile-time type parameters and serve as base-class/interface for run-time polymorphism, which is perhaps where your confusion comes from, however both kinds of polymorphism are inherently different.

```
pub struct Asset<'a> {
    name: &str,
    theme_park: Box<ThemePark<> + 'a> // <-- This won't compile, as ThemePark needs 2 type arguments
}
```

Then you should NOT be using compile-time polymorphism, and instead define `ThemePark` as:

```
pub trait ThemePark {
    fn create(square_size: u32, name: &str) -> Self;
    fn get_attractions(&self) -> Vec<Box<Attraction>>;
    fn get_visitors(&self) -> Vec<Box<Visitor>>;
}
```

By instantiating a `ThemePark<A, V>` you create a theme park which can only ever contain *one type* of attractions (it's all Haunted Houses here, no Flume Ride sorry!) and *one type* of visitors (only Elderly Guys in, no Elderly Ladies or Kids).

Comment: The problem in `Asset` persists though. I cannot have an `Asset` that has a member of `Box<ThemePark>` because `ThemePark` cannot be made into an object. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: @Sorona That's probably because `create` has no receiver, right? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159771/why-can-a-trait-not-construct-itself

Comment: Still not a solution to my problem. Of course the individual `Attraction` or `Visitor` are different structs, so an impl of `ThemePark` will create `ElderlyGuys` as Visitors and then I get that `ElderlyGuys` was given but `Visitors` was expected.

Comment: @Sorona instead of directly inserting an `ElderlyGuy` into the `Vec`, insert `Box::new(ElderlyGuy::new())` into the `Vec`.

Comment: @NovaDenizen I do just that (else I would get an error that a `Box` was expected while an `ElderlyGuy` was given), but then I get that `Box<ElderlyGuy>` is not the same as `Box<Visitor>` and the latter was expected!

Comment: Maybe you didn't declare the type of the vector.  See [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=62faba37b5f0830cda9133d5530bc560&version=stable), especially the comment in `make_buffet()`.