# Why does returning `Self` in trait work, but returning `Option<Self>` requires `Sized`?

Tags: rust, traits

This trait definition compiles fine:

```
trait Works {
    fn foo() -> Self;
}
```

This, however, does lead to an error:

```
trait Errors {
    fn foo() -> Option<Self>;
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     fn foo() -> Option<Self>;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Self`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = help: consider adding a `where Self: std::marker::Sized` bound
  = note: required by `std::option::Option`
```

With the `: Sized` supertrait bound, it works.

I know that the `Self` type in traits is not automatically bound to be `Sized`. And I understand that `Option<Self>` cannot be returned (via the stack) unless it is sized (which, in turn, requires `Self` to be sized). However, the same would go for `Self` as return type, right? It also cannot be stored on the stack unless it's sized.

**Why doesn't the first trait definition already trigger that error?**

(*[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938499/why-is-the-sized-bound-necessary-in-this-trait) is related, but it doesn't answer my exact question – unless I didn't understand it.*)

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html for other people like me who trust the compiler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two sets of checks happening here, which is why the difference appears confusing.

1. Each type in the function signature is checked for validity. `Option` inherently requires `T: Sized`. A return type that doesn't require `Sized` is fine:

   ```
   trait Works {
       fn foo() -> Box<Self>;
   }
   ```

   The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465962/155423) covers this well.
2. Any function **with a body** also checks that all of the parameters are `Sized`. Trait functions without a body do not have this check applied.

   Why is this useful? Allowing unsized types to be used in trait methods is a key part of allowing *by-value trait objects*, a very useful feature. For example, `FnOnce` does not require that `Self` be `Sized`:

   ```
   pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
       type Output;
       extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
   }
   ```

   ```
   fn call_it(f: Box<dyn FnOnce() -> i32>) -> i32 {
       f()
   }

   fn main() {
       println!("{}", call_it(Box::new(|| 42)));
   }
   ```

A big thanks to [pnkfelix and nikomatsakis for answering my questions on this topic](https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/144729-wg-traits/topic/questions.20from.20Stack.20Overflow/near/157298199).

Comment: BTW, `Box<dyn FnOnce()>` works on nightly now ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b00c85886a8f8447f8763d577697d16)). See [#54183](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/54183).

Comment: @FrancisGagné hmm. [The docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html) haven’t been updated so I didn’t even think to try.

Comment: Are closures actually unsized, though? My understanding is that every closure implicitly creates its own unique type, but that type is sized.

Answer (score 11):

It's in the error message:

> `` = note: required by `std::option::Option` ``

`Option` requires the type to be `Sized` because it owns its data. All type parameters to a concrete type definition are by default constrained as `Sized`. Some types choose to opt out with a `?Sized` bound but `Option` does not.

> Why doesn't the first trait definition already trigger that error?

I think this is a conscious design decision, due to history, future-proofing and ergonomics.

First of all, `Self` is not assumed to be `Sized` in a trait definition because people are going to forget to write `where Self: ?Sized`, and those traits would be less useful. Letting traits be as flexible as possible *by default* is a sensible design philosophy; push errors to impls or make developers explicitly add constraints where they are needed.

With that in mind, imagine that trait definitions did *not* permit unsized types to be returned by a method. *Every* trait method that returns `Self` would have to also specify `where Self: Sized`. Apart from being a lot of visual noise, this would be bad for future language development: if unsized types are allowed to be returned in the future (e.g. to be used with [placement-new](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1228)), then all of these existing traits would be overly constrained.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `Option` is just the tip of the iceberg and the others have already explained that bit; I'd like to elaborate on [your question in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465400/why-does-returning-self-in-trait-work-but-returning-optionself-requires/54477490#comment95740147_54465962):

> is there a way I can implement fn `foo() -> Self` with `Self` not being
>   `Sized`? Because if there is no way to do that, I don't see the point in
>   allowing to return `Self` without a `Sized` bound.

That method indeed makes it impossible (at least currently) to utilize the trait as a trait object due to 2 issues:

1. [Method has no receiver](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#method-has-no-receiver):

> Methods that do not take a `self` parameter can't be called since there
>   won't be a way to get a pointer to the method table for them.

2. [Method references the Self type in its arguments or return type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#method-references-the-self-type-in-its-arguments-or-return-type):

This renders the trait not object-safe, i.e. it is impossible to create a trait object from it.

You are still perfectly able to use it for other things, though:

```
trait Works {
    fn foo() -> Self;
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Foo;

impl Works for Foo {
    fn foo() -> Self {
        Foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Foo::foo(), Foo);
}
```