# How to handle `Self` in Rust procedual macros?

Tags: rust, quote, rust-proc-macros, syn

I'm trying to create a derive macro in Rust to create instances, as an example, which should implement following trait:

```
pub trait MyTrait {
    fn my_default() -> Option<Self>;
}
```

I use `syn` and `quote` to parse and generate the AST, as following:

```
#[proc_macro_derive(MyTrait)]
pub fn my_default_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Use `syn` to parse
    // ...

    let gen = quote! {
        impl #impl_generics_strait::MyTrait for #name #ty_generics #where_clause {
            fn my_default() -> Option<Self>{
                // ...
            }
        }
    };

    gen.into()
}
```

As the compiler doest not know what `Self` is at compile time, foregoing will cause error:

```
the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to use Self in `proc_macro_derive`?
- How?

BTW, I'm trying to use ident instead, and will post progress here later.

**Update**:

- It turns out, the error is caused by the trait declaration, not the `proc_macro_derive`. To fix, `Sized` should be added to the trait name.

Comment: This has [nothing to do with macros](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7638ef7b828950991b75da7c11d1db7e).

Comment: You can make your trait work by [adding a `: Sized` bound on its declaration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=024fa70253de0de29bf83675141cc525).

Comment: @mcarton Yeah, you are right.

Comment: @hxpax in this situation, will you close the question or self answer it or waiting for someone to write answer to approve?

Comment: @Websterix Tried to close, but could not find out a proper reason item. Will anwser it myself if mcarton do not.

Comment: This strikes me as a "can not be reproduced" kind of question because, although not a typo, it's based on a mistaken premise (that the error has something to do with macros) and was resolved in a way unlikely to help future readers. It could probably be marked instead as a dupe of some other question, possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54465400/3650362).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does returning \`Self\` in trait work, but returning \`Option<Self>\` requires \`Sized\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465400/why-does-returning-self-in-trait-work-but-returning-optionself-requires)