# Is it possible to provide default implementation of chainable trait methods?

Tags: rust, traits, chainable

The goal would be to have something similar to ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=5162a27ec1989ea5d87724dabaa10932)):

```
trait T {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String;
    fn forwardable_append_attribute(mut self, new_value: &str) -> Self {
        let attribute = self.get_mutable_attribute();
        attribute.push_str(new_value);
        println!("{}", attribute);
        self
    }
}

struct S {
    attribute: String,
}

impl T for S {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        &mut self.attribute
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S {
        attribute: "init".to_string(),
    }
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_1")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_2")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_3");
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:3:37
  |
3 |     fn forwardable_append_attribute(mut self, new_value: &str) -> Self {
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
help: consider further restricting `Self`
  |
3 |     fn forwardable_append_attribute(mut self, new_value: &str) -> Self where Self: std::marker::Sized {
  |                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: function arguments must have a statically known size, borrowed types always have a known size
  |
3 |     fn forwardable_append_attribute(&mut self, new_value: &str) -> Self {
  |                                     ^
```

An alternative would be to define the trait method for each object implementing the trait but that introduces duplication between all sub objects ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0037e3477d18871b71b2cd0af217a7e0)):

```
trait T {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String;
    fn forwardable_append_attribute(self, new_value: &str) -> Self;
}

struct S {
    attribute: String,
}

impl T for S {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        &mut self.attribute
    }
    fn forwardable_append_attribute(mut self, new_value: &str) -> Self {
        let attribute = self.get_mutable_attribute();
        attribute.push_str(new_value);
        println!("{}", attribute);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S {
        attribute: "init".to_string(),
    }
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_1")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_2")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_3");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's complaining that you can't return `self`, since `self` might not be `Sized`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30941589/5923139) So, you can just add a bound that `Self` must be `Sized` on the method:

```rust
trait T {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String;
    fn forwardable_append_attribute(mut self, new_value: &str) -> Self
    // note this trait bound
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        let attribute = self.get_mutable_attribute();
        attribute.push_str(new_value);
        println!("{}", attribute);
        self
    }
}

struct S {
    attribute: String,
}

impl T for S {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        &mut self.attribute
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S {
        attribute: "init".to_string(),
    }
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_1")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_2")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_3");
}
```

Note that you could also put the `Sized` bound on the trait itself instead of the method, which would look like `trait T: Sized {...}`. You should do this if the trait only provides the chainable method, so there's no point in implementing the trait for a type that can't have the chainable method. Alternatively, instead of moving `self` into the function, you can take a mutable reference and return the mutable reference, removing the need for `Sized`:

```rust
trait T {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String;
    // note the &mut self and &mut Self
    fn forwardable_append_attribute(&mut self, new_value: &str) -> &mut Self {
        let attribute = self.get_mutable_attribute();
        attribute.push_str(new_value);
        println!("{}", attribute);
        self
    }
}

struct S {
    attribute: String,
}

impl T for S {
    fn get_mutable_attribute(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        &mut self.attribute
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S {
        attribute: "init".to_string(),
    }
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_1")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_2")
    .forwardable_append_attribute("new_3");
}
```